# How to access a member variable of different function in a codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
//first function
function insertdigit(){
$userdigit=5;
$flag = $this->usermodel->userdigitmodel($userdigit);


        $value = array(
            'result' => $flag
        );
        echo json_encode($value);
        if ($flag == true) {
              return $userdigit;
        } else {
        }

}
//second function
function usedigit(){
$data['userdigit']=$this->insertdigit();
}
```

but i get `{"result":true}` goes back to the function? how to access a member variable in a different member function

Comment: Check your model function userdigitmodel you must be returning boolean true instead of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `echo json_encode($value);` in your code.

Comment: that means you will always return the value of json_encode($value). instead of returning $userdigit

Comment: then try to add your result in the $value.. ie: `$value=array('result'=>$flag,'userdigit'=>$userdigit);`

Comment: you dont need this then... `if ($flag == true) {
              return $userdigit;
        } else {
        }`

Comment: {"result":true,"userdigit":"353701"} i get this now

Comment: Is it the userdigit value you need to access?

Comment: ya!! i need just the userdigit value ... my question is how to access a value from a different function in a controller

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a parameter in several functions on your controller, you have to create it outside your function so it will be available for all your controller functions.

So, in your case it should be something like this:

```
class Test extends Controller
{
    private $userdigit; //here you can set a default value if necessary: private $userdigit = 5

     function insertdigit(){
        $this->userdigit=5;
        $flag = $this->usermodel->userdigitmodel($this->userdigit);


        $value = array(
            'result' => $flag
        );
        echo json_encode($value);
        if ($flag == true) {
              return $this->userdigit;
        } else {
        }

    }
    //second function
    function usedigit(){
      $data['userdigit']=$this->userdigit;
    }

}
```

This way your `userdigit` variable is available for all your functions. With `$this` you are telling PHP that you are trying to access something inside the class.

This link contain more and useful information: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Is that what you really need?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
function insertdigit() 
{
    $userDigit = 5;
    $flag = $this->usermodel->userdigitmodel($userDigit);
    $value = array
    (
        'result' => $flag
    );
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
    {
        echo json_encode($value);
    }
    if ($flag == true) 
    {
        return $userdigit;
    } 
    else 
    {
    }
}
//second function
function usedigit()
{
    $data['userdigit'] = $this->insertdigit();
}
```

The above code, in `insertdigit` detects if there is an Ajax request and if so, it will echo out the `json_encode`d data. If you call it in an normal request, i.e. via `usedigit` it won't echo the `json_encode`d data (unless you are calling `usedigit` via an Ajax request).

Your question doesn't really explain what you are doing, so it's hard to explain a better solution, however, if you are trying to access a "variable" in more than one place, you should really separate your code so you have a single entry point for that variable.

Is your variable dynamic, or is it static?